# Different start and end frame for each action

Tags: animation, timeline

I have 2 actions, walk and idle.  The idle animation is much longer than the walk.  Each time I want to check my animations, I have to adjust the timeline ending frame, right now that's not too bad, as I only have 2 animations, but could be a pain when I want to go through more animations.

So the question is; Is there a way to set a start / end frame for each action?

[image]

Comment: I just adjusted my answer as I realised I forgot the best shortcut.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't set a start/end frame for each action as the start and end frame is a setting that is global for the current scene.

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl + End</kbd> while your cursor is over the timeline will set the end frame to the current frame. A quick click at the last keyframe and a keystroke is easier than manually entering the end frame number. You can also press <kbd>Ctrl + Home</kbd> to set the start frame. This only works when the cursor is atop the timeline panel.

There is also a [preview frame range setting](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/timeline.html#header-controls), this allows you to adjust the start and end frames while animating without changing the frames that are used when rendering. This is useful when you only want to play a section of the animation that you are concentrating on.

The preview range leads to a shortcut that makes changing the frame range even easier while animating, press <kbd>P</kbd> and drag from the start to end frame to set the preview range. This works in any of the time based editors - timeline, dopesheet, graph editor, NLA editor, video sequencer.

Comment: Note that in blender 2.8 this was changed to Ctrl+Home and Ctrl+End

Answer (score 1):

There is always a bunch of different ways to do stuff in Blender. One of which is to use NLA editor to make shorter animation repeat for all time needed like this:
[image]